# cmd.exe opens then immediately closes

Tags: windows-10, command-line

Desktop I7-4790 - 16g memory - W10 latest incarnation - Start/Run/cmd.exe, opens then immediately closes. Sometimes you get a flash of the whole window but mostly just a flash of the min/max/exit buttons. Can anyone suggest a fix?

Fixes I've tried : Tried RKill, Malwarebytes, Avast freebie runs permanently, everything up to date.

Background : It first happened 3 weeks ago just after windows did its latest massive update, so I formatted the windows drive (SSD) and reinstalled w10. Command box worked fine until windows did the same update again - back to square 1. Is this MS telling us to convert to Powershell????

I've put cmd.exe on a stick from a different machine not affected, when I run it from the stick or anywhere else on the desktop I get the same result.

Comment: https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/11/18/windows_cmdexe_deposed_by_powershell/

Comment: Welcome to the site, Dave. This site works a little different than the typical forum. This is a Q&A site. So, you need to ask a specific question we can answer (or attempt to answer). The only question you have here is if MS is trying to tell us to convert to Powershell. That question is off-topic because it is not something we can answer. Please use the **[edit]** feature to add a question we can answer.

Comment: If you open start, and type cmd, before pressing enter, does it indeed say Command Prompt? It is possible it actually finds a .cmd script and you start that instead.

Comment: @LPChip yes - all that works correctly - I can even right click the Command Prompt up the top and Run as Administrator which does exactly the same thing (start/stop)

Comment: Can you start Windows in "Safe Mode with Command Prompt"?

Comment: Yes - that works fine - not much good for day-to-day stuff though.

Comment: What edition of Windows? Is this machine a member of a domain? Does the problem occur if you logon using the built-in Administrator account? What happens if you create then run a batch file that only contains the command `pause`?

Comment: W10 Pro - 10-0-16299 - not domain - problem occurs however i'm logged on - batch file with a pause does exactly the same